# Module Object is Not Callable

Tags: python, object, module

For some reason I'm getting a module object is not callable error on this code. I don't really get why? Whats going on and how do I fix it? :(

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
name = raw_input('What is your name')
end_time = time.time()
total_time=end_time-start_time
print total_time
```

and the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "time.py", line 1, in <module> 
import time File "/Users/Me/randomcode/time.py", line 2, in <module> 
    start_time = time.time() 
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: The code is correct. Please provide the expception's stack trace.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time.py", line 1, in <module>
    import time
  File "/Users/Thambapillai/randomcode/time.py", line 2, in <module>
    start_time = time.time()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @Ravin: Edit the stacktrace into your question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't call your own script file `time.py` ... it's importing itself!

Comment: Actually scratch that - I just deleted the other file and it worked! Thanks!! :D

Comment: @Ravin The ✓ icon is your friend!